# SwiftUI Calling NetworkModel from the View

Tags: swiftui

I have been been reading a lot of about SwiftUI architecture. I read about MVVM, TCA, MVC etc. I am writing an app, where I have to get data from the JSON API and display it on the screen. I am following Apple's code samples and here is what I am doing.

For that I created a NetworkModel.

```
class NetworkModel {
    
    func getPosts() async throws -> [Post] {
        
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!)
        let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
        return posts
    }
    
}
```

**Post.swift**

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}
```

**PostListView**

```
struct PostListView: View {
    
    @State private var posts: [Post] = []
    let networkModel = NetworkModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(posts, id: \.id) { post in
            Text(post.title)
        }.task {
            do {
                await networkModel.getPosts()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works. Is this the right approach? I come from React background so in React if there is a component that is using state and that state will only be used for that component then we simply use private/local state.

I did not create any View Models etc for this app. Are VM's going to benefit me in someway?

Comment: This is an opinion based question therefore out of scope for SO. The right way is what works for you and your use case.

Comment: Thanks! But if I don't View Models will I run into some issues in the future.

Comment: Architecture is about order, decoupling and reusability. As long as you follow some pattern you’ll be ok. Nobody here can tell you if you will need a “ViewModel” in the future, we don’t know your app plans. All SO can offer is a long debate and you will end up in the same place. You can also choose no pattern and end up with “spaghetti” code. It all works, engineers use some kind of architecture. Some of them are really cemented in their ways but most can argue the topic both ways. The debates are all over the internet if you have researched as you said you know the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example code is how I would approach using a `NetworkModel`.
Caveat, without dealing with the errors.

It creates a `NetworkModel` as a `ObservableObject`, which will make it easier
to update the data and have the UI refreshed automatically. The code uses
only **one source of truth**, the `@StateObject var networkModel = NetworkModel()`,
and nothing else. This, I believe is important for an architecture.

`Is this the right approach?`, well that is up to you to determine, by understanding
the various info you read, and your own experience.

```
struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let userId: Int
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let body: String
}

@MainActor
class NetworkModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
    
    func getPosts() async throws {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else {return}
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            self.posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var networkModel = NetworkModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List (networkModel.posts) { post in
            Text(post.title)
        }
        .task {
            do {
                try await networkModel.getPosts()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The info at the following link, gives some good explanations about how to manage data in your app and how SwiftUI has already a lot of structure/architecture built in to help you:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: One question. In this scenario, if I have to sort the results in ascending or descending order then where would that code go? In the View, NetworkModel or somewhere else.

Comment: It depends on the use case, but by and large, I would put it in the View where you want to display the info in the desired "format", like this:
 `List (networkModel.posts.sorted(by: {$0.title < $1.title}))`. You can also sort inplace, like this `self.posts.sort(by: {$0.title < $1.title})` just after the decoding for example.

Answer (score 1):

SwiftUI is an architecture in itself, it's best to just learn it. E.g. learn the `View` struct, learn how `body` func is called if a `let` property or an `@State` or `@Binding` changes. It's really quite simple.